# Error: Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0 in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

hi my gradle version is 7.3.3 and my flutter version is 2.8.1

this is  error when I run the app  :

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
    
    * What went wrong:
    A problem occurred configuring project ':path_provider_android'
    > Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':path_provider_android:classpath'
       > Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0.
         Searched in the following locations:
           - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.3.0/gradle-3.3.0.pom
           - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.3.0/gradle-3.3.0.pom
```

Comment: Did you try upgrading the version to the latest one(7.0.4) ?

Comment: No gradle version  :  7.3.3

Comment: As far as I know AGP's latest version is 7.0.4 and you can specify that 7.3.3 in distribution URL of Gradle wrapper properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved :)

just update  gradle version in (gradle-wrapper.properties ) :

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bICDH.png)

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue go and check google() repo in your project's level build.gradle file

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}
```

Comment: but i have it :(

Comment: Try rearranging the repositories from { jcenter() google() }  to repositories { google() jcenter() } and see if it can work

Answer (score 0):

Jcenter its suppose to close on 1 Feb. But today i started having problems. On a research i found this [Flutter migration jcenter to mavenCentral](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/82847)

Now theres a big problem bc a lot of pubs depend on this change... Now im waiting the community to fix it

Answer (score 0):

Update the Gradle version and also Update the kotlin version

[image]

[image]